# Java for loop tricky iteration

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I've run the code multiple times wondering what's wrong.

this simple for loop should run 4 times. why is it running only twice??
Did i miss anything. I'm using android-studio stock emulator api-28 for debugging.

```
boolean[] booleans = {false, false, false, false};

for(boolean b :  booleans){

     System.out.println(b);
}
```

[image: log cat output]

please check the edited code and log cat output.

[image: edited code]

Comment: The problem is not with the code, it's probably related to some kind of output buffering issue. Print something after the last println statement and you'll see this is the case. Note that sometimes standard error can overtake standard output. You can try to flush the standard output, but the problem could be with the specific debugger / console configuration.

Comment: your output is showing a GC output which interrupted creation of your activity. Your other false printouts are most likely somewhere below the GC output.

Comment: Ugly hack: add a sleep of a second before you exit the main loop, so the process ends some time after printing. Otherwise you need to look into your environment (settings).

Comment: Learning to debug would be a useful survival skill in the code jungle. :)

Comment: I have tested this code on jdoodle.com and its working fine

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I've tried filtering the output. It's strange. the problem could be with debugger.

Comment: @diginoise I've gone through filtering logcat outputs. there are no false printouts. the problem could be with debugger.

Comment: try concating while outputting `System.out.println(""+b);` and check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first glance, in Android Studio it prints twice or 3 times when debugging, in the Debug tab, **but**
the truth is this:

```
I/System.out: Start
I/System.out: false
I/System.out: false
I/chatty: uid=10075(u0_a75) com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxx identical 1 line
I/System.out: false
I/System.out: End
```

or

```
I/System.out: Start
I/System.out: false
I/chatty: uid=10075(u0_a75) com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxx identical 2 lines
I/System.out: false
I/System.out: End
```

as you can see AS instead of printing

```
I/System.out: false
```

prefers to print

```
I/chatty: uid=10075(u0_a75) com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxx identical 2 lines
```

Why? I can't say. 
Maybe something similar happens in the Logcat tab. 
Yes it is similar in the Logcat tab:

```
2018-12-04 14:16:17.756 2209-2209/com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxx I/System.out: false
2018-12-04 14:16:23.902 2209-2209/com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxx I/chatty: uid=10075(u0_a75) com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxx  identical 2 lines
2018-12-04 14:16:24.929 2209-2209/com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxx I/System.out: false
2018-12-04 14:16:25.860 2209-2209/com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxx I/System.out: End
```

**So finally**:
remove filtering of your output window by **deleting "System"** and you will see output either like

```
I/System.out: false
```

or

```
identical 2 lines
```

Comment: But I don't see those "chatty" lines in the output of Karan either. Could you explain why that is?

Comment: I can't say, these results are from my testing.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes it's the Debug tab. Maybe something similar happens in the Logcat tab

Comment: Yeah, and if it sometimes performs it and sometimes not it may be timing related as well. But 3 lines... sheesh. Maybe they should not let Detritus do the counting.

Comment: OK, so possibly the chatty output is suppressed.

Comment: Maybe, or is the output filtered?

Comment: Duh, it reads "system" in the logcat window on the top right.